# How can I make a transition animation work with a css hoverbox?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, css-transitions

I am trying to make a set of html + css hover boxes.  These are similar to a dropdown menu.

The desired behavior is when the user hovers on a box, another box scrolls down over the first box.

Right now the boxes appear over the text and respond to styles, but I can not seem to trigger a transition effect.

I have tried to transition max-height css property using the following code:

```
<div id="boxbar">
      <ul id="boxbar-table">
        <li class="boxbar-col boxbar-col-left" id="boxbar-col-1">
          Services <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
          <ul class='boxbar-rollover'>
            <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="boxbar-col boxbar-col-right" id="boxbar-col-2">
          Services <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
          <ul class='boxbar-rollover'>
            <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
/* Hide nested ul by default */

#boxbar ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
}

#boxbar ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

#boxbar ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
#boxbar ul li ul li {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 2s;
}

/* Nested dropdown show */
#boxbar ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: -258px;
  width: 200%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
#boxbar ul .boxbar-col-left:hover ul {
  left: 0;
}
#boxbar ul .boxbar-col-right:hover ul {
  left: -100%;
}

#boxbar ul li:hover ul li {
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  background: #e9e9e8;
  max-height: 302px;
}
```

Here is the full code on github.
https://github.com/twheelertech/boxbar

This adjusts the max-height but the height does not transition on hover. I have tried targeting the parent ul but can not get the transitions to work.

I want the second box to seem to scroll down.

How can I do this?  Do I need to change the html structure?

Comment: If you hover over Box A which causes Box B to cover the original box then you will no longer be hovering Box A...so it will fail.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the issue.